# Java reading a text file by character - unicode 254 and 255 appears out of nowhere

Tags: java, file, unicode, text-files, bufferedreader

From the code below i read a text file that contains a character 'a' (unicode 97)

```
int ini ; 
    // Buffered Reader Text file read per character
    while((ini=jer.read())!=(-1)){
        char inp = (char)ini;
        System.out.println(inp);
        if (listahan.containsKey(inp)) {
                listahan.put(inp,listahan.get(inp) + 1);
            } else {
                listahan.put(inp, 1);
            }
    }
// ENHANCED FOR LOOP FOR DISPLAYING IN CONSOLE
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : listahan.entrySet()){
    System.out.printf("%1d.) %-15s : %-3d%n", ctr++, e.getKey(), e.getValue());

}
```

the output was :

```
1.)                 : 1  // (must be a null)
2.) a               : 1  
3.) þ               : 1  
4.) ÿ               : 1
```

why is the output not like this one?:

```
1.) a                 :1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran into a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), being U+FEFF, which is, when read as separate bytes, equivalent to 254 and 255.

This (together with the occurence of the null) probably implies that the file is encoded in [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) or [UCS-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2) (aka widestring, wchar, …). I suggest you have a read up on unicode encodings if you don't know what that means. For this, I recommend the great article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks, by the way how could i represent U+FEFF in an escape sequence in java? @Jonas Wielicki